# How to setup offline maps?

Tags: pokemon-go

Multiple sources [like this](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/11/12148496/pokemon-go-battery-data-usage) are reporting that since pokemon go is using the Google maps API one can simply download the offline maps of the area he is in and voilà.... pokemon go no more needs to download the map data of that area.

But since downloading offline maps does nothing else than downloading a file which can be launched with the googlemaps app to access that area offline, I was skeptical how pokemon go should even know about the offline data beeing available. I gave it a try anyway and noticed.... Nothing...

So in case this trick is working at all, one needs at least somehow let the app know that the data is available allready and not required to be downloaded. As thats what my app keeps doing, every time I start the app I'm loosing a lot of time untill the map is onscreen.

So my question is: Is it verifyed that this method is working?
In case it is, how do I setup the offline data to be preferential accessed?

Comment: What are the exact advantages of this? Lower battery/data drain?

Comment: @MarioGarcia: both points

Comment: Don't think you will notice a big impact then...Most of the battery drain will come from the screen being on. And data drain is pretty low even without the trick. I mean, it's probably a good idea to do this for your area, but won't make a big difference I guess

Comment: @MarioGarcia: Well the main problem I'm trying to solve is that my connection is so bad that as soon I'm leaving home and my 200mb/month mobile traffic are reached I can't play the game anymore as it fails to load. I was expecting this could solve my problem.

Comment: @Zaibis Honestly the map data is probably cached after you visit an area. We've agreed they use Google Maps and I've drove from Virginia to Detroit with Google maps as navigation and I used around 60mb. That's a 12 hour trip. So you probably won't notice a difference at all because you're not loading new areas for 12 hours straight..

Answer (score 8):

It is unlikely that this will work. smartphone apps are sandboxed, meaning each app essentially runs in a separate environment with no access to any of the phone's features. To access resources outside of that sandbox, apps need permission from the user. That's why apps ask for permission when you install them or do something that requires access to non-standard things like contacts, camera, call information,...

Both Google Maps and Pokémon Go are sandboxed in this manner, meaning that any maps you download in Google Maps will only be available in the Google Mapps app. There might be a way for other apps to access these offline maps, but that requires the other app to:

1. Be aware that the Google Maps app is installed;
2. Be aware that the user has offline maps on their device;
3. Be aware that the user has an offline map of their current location;
4. Have a way for this external map to be imported into the app;
5. Know when the user exits the offline map area.
6. Be able to fluently switch between an offline map and a downloaded map.

In addition, an offline map might be outdated depending on when it was last updated. Roads may be added or removed, Points of Interest might be added or removed, street names might have changed, and in some extreme cases, an entire village might have been moved several miles. If your offline map is too old, it might not be compatible with the Niantic app, leading to possible claims that you are cheating.

Comment: Is it possible Pokemon Go caches map data of areas around you so that it's not constantly reloading it, and checks for changes via Google Maps API? I use a considerably tiny amount of data for Go and Google Maps when i'm using it as navigation.

Comment: @Insane Yes, that's possible and very likely. On a short scale (like a few weeks or months), you can definitely cache maps. However, in some regions, a cached map may be out of date within less than a year, and it's possible that some people have outdated offline maps. It's unlikely since offline Google maps expire after 30 days, but some people with unique (read: hacked) configurations might have maps that haven't expired yet.